# how to stick a div element to the top of the scroll using iscroll for mobile?

Tags: jquery, ios, scroll

I want to make an app for IOS similar to Ditto, where there is an element that sticks at the top when you scroll down, I am making my own using Iscroll but the problem is that I can't call my positioning function using the momentum and other problem is that in ios doesn't work well.

This is a part of my code

```
function stickDiv() {

    if(($('#wrapper').offset().top > $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top))
    {
    $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
    $('#sticky').css({'top' : (myScroll.y*-1)});
    }
    else
    $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
 }

function loaded() {
var topSticky = $('#sticky').offset().top;
alert(topSticky);
myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', {
momentum: true,
bounce:true,
hScrollbar: false,
vScrollbar: false,
onScrollMove: stickDiv ,
onScrollEnd: stickDiv
});

}
```

Div sticky is what I want to move, and sticky-anchor is the div previously to sticky.

If there is another alternative besides Iscroll that would help. Thanks.